# Build xamarin android project unsucessfully,error XA4212

Tags: android, xamarin.android

At visual Studio 2017 15.4,everything goes fine.But after I upgrated to 15.5,my xamarin android project can not be built successfully,showing:

```
error XA4212: Type `Android.Support.V4.App.JobIntentService/JobServiceEngineImpl` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported.
```

Comment: I also got the same problem but couldn't resolve it. Xamarin.Android on VS for Mac. Any other advice?

Comment: Can you show us your package.config / your dependencies (incl. version)?

Answer (score 37):

Following @Ironman answer, this happens with Xamarin.Android 8.0, so I set the property to **false** in the project .csproj file in the following section.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Other properties -->
    <AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject>false</AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In most cases **you should add the property** as it doesn't exist by default.

Now you can build and run the app normally, only with a warning.

Beware that are other **PropertyGroup** tags inside the .csproj file, that are specific to build conditions.

You can see the other build properties and configurations in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/Documentation/build_process.md

Comment: There is no "AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject" property in my project .csproj file,so I add this property and set it to false.The project can be built and deployed successfully on my phone,but can not run.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @LiuFeng, I will correct the answer. Did you clean the project? Did you to update the nuget packages to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned the project and all the nuget packages are updated to latest version.I am new to xamarin Android and looking forward for your help. Thanks very much.

Comment: Sadly I'm also a Xamarin beginner. I think this is a problem that might be solved in an update. Maybe you should try posting in the Xamarin forums as it seems like a recent problem.

Comment: I have two more questions about this. Firstly, How do you change the propertys in csproj file? Ues text editor? Secondly, what is the condition of property group? "Debug", "Debug|AnyCPU", "Release|AnyCPU" or all of above? Thanks!

Comment: Yes use a text editor. You can add a new <PropertyGroup> element to add this one in it. If you don't specify a Condition value, then it will be global and applied to All configurations

Comment: This worked for me but I am curious... where does one go to learn these "hidden" configuration options? Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: @tutiplain Actually I found  a little documentation on Github when looking for AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject. But it seem that the problem was fixed with later Xamarin releases.

Comment: Link is broken. Do you mean https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/README.md?

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject :**

> A boolean property that determines whether types may implement
>   `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` without also inheriting from
>   `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`:

```
class BadType : IJavaObject {
    public IntPtr Handle {
        get {return IntPtr.Zero;}
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

When True, such types will generate an XA4212 error, otherwise a XA4212 warning will be generated.

Support for this property was added in Xamarin.Android 8.1.

This property is True by default.

Comment: So what exactly I must do to fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So how can I fix this error？

Comment: Just remove Xamarin.Android.JobDispatcher package and then add it again. help for me.

Comment: I also got the same problem but couldn't resolve it. Xamarin.Android on VS for Mac. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had to Inherit Lava.Lang.object and removed Android.Runtime.IJavaObject to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by right clicking the solution and choosing Clean. If you get a message asking you to verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager after you try cleaning, you can find instructions on how to resolve that issue [here](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1866).

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this error as well upon updating visual studio.  I finally tracked it down to the csproj still pointing to the v4.1 version of mono.android.  Going in and pointing it to the newest version (8.1 as of my writing) corrected it for me.

`<Reference Include="Mono.Android">
<HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\Mono.Android.dll<HintPath> </Reference>`