# How install Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging with Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install the nuget [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/) package on a clean empty project with [xamarin.forms.maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/) which fails because of version conflict by `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` dependency.

My Xamarin.Forms csproj contains the following nuget dependencies:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The Android csproj contains the following nuget dependencies:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
      <Version>2.5.0.280555</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I try to install the nuget package [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/) it fails with:

```
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging -IgnoreDependencies
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-
semver2/xamarin.firebase.messaging/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-
semver2/xamarin.firebase.messaging/index.json 128ms
Restoring packages for 
D:\Projects\mfe\App3\App3\App3.Android\App3.Android.csproj...
Install-Package : Version conflict detected for 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement. Reference the package directly from the 
project to resolve this issue. 
App3.Android -> Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.0 -> 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 60.1142.0) 
App3.Android -> Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 2.3.0 -> 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 42.1021.1 -> 
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1021.1).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging -IgnoreDependencies
[...]
```

Is there any workaround for this issue? Something like a fallback to version?

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT**
>
> With my answer below we can build and run, but when try to show a map tons of java exceptions occurs.
>
> **Definitive solution**: The real problem was Xamarin.Forms.Maps dependency with Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps (>= 42.1021.1). I thought that the latest version was installed due to '>=', but version installed is 42.1021.1. In Android csproj I set Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps to 60.1142.0 version and now Firebase and Maps can be installed and works like a charm! :)

Following the Matt Ward answer I'm getting errors like:

```
Type Android.Gms.Maps.Model.CameraPosition` implements 
Android.Runtime.IJavaObject but does not inherit Java.Lang.Object or Java.Lang.Throwable. This is not supported.    .Android`
```

, as Briefkasten has commented.

To avoid this errors I set the AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject property to false in the Android project .csproj ([See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727884/build-xamarin-android-project-unsucessfully-error-xa4212?rq=1)).

After that I get new errors like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzat
```

I´ve installed Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.0, the same version of GooglePlayServices installed previously:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base">
      <Version>60.1142.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Now I can compile and run my Android project with Firebase and Maps :´)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a explicit PackageReferences for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.0 and for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks 60.1142.0 then the NuGet package restore seems to work.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="26.1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" Version="60.1142.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" Version="60.1142.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
      <Version>2.5.0.280555</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging">
      <Version>60.1142.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I just tried your original package references and then used the information in the restore failure to see what explicit references were needed. The first failure was:

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement. Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 weaga32ewgegw (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (>= 60.1142.0) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (>= 60.1142.0) 
 weaga32ewgegw (>= 1.0.0) -> Xamarin.Forms.Maps (>= 2.5.0.280555) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps (>= 42.1021.1) -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (>= 42.1021.1).
```

Then I added the explicit PackageReference as indicated in the NuGet restore output, retried, etc, until the restore was successful.

The Android project I was using had a TargetFrameworkVersion of v8.1.

Worth testing if this all still works since that is quite a version jump from 42.1021.1 to 60.1142.0.

Comment: I achieved as you descriped to install the nuget package, but I'm getting errors like: `Type `Android.Gms.Maps.Model.CameraPosition` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported. .Android`