# Xamarin Android Google Play Service Package Build Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have installed the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base nuget package into my existing Xamarin.Android application. Since then, it fails to build with the following error message:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error: error XA4212: Type `Android.Support.V4.App.JobIntentService/JobServiceEngineImpl` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported. (Happimeter.Watch.Droid).

My question: how do I fix this error?

EDIT 1:
The following packages have been added as a result of installing the nuget package:

```
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 60.1142.1' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 60.1142.1' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks 60.1142.1' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 60.1142.1' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.9' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 26.0.2' to Happimeter.Watch.Droid
```

EDIT 2:

This is my setup:

```
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac 
Version 7.3.3 (build 5)
Runtime:
Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Package version: 504010007

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 8.1.3.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/mariusstein/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
    6.0 (API level 23)
    7.1 (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.3
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.1

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

[Here](https://github.com/mstein11/GooglePlayServicesTest) is a sample project where you can reproduce the issue:

EDIT 3: 
As per [Build xamarin android project unsucessfully,error XA4212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727884/build-xamarin-android-project-unsucessfully-error-xa4212) I a just added

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Other properties -->
    <AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject>false</AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This turned the error into a warning. However this solution seems rather unclean. If anyone has a suggestion as to how to fix this issue permanently, I would like to hear it.

EDIT 4: 
**Updating to Android Target API 27 resolved the error/warning.**

Comment: What version of libraries are you using here?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my post. Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Is this reproducible? Can you attach a project that demonstrates this issue? Secondly, what version of Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin.Android are you on?

Comment: I edited the question again. I will try to create a reproducible project and attach it here soon.

Comment: The problem is indeed reproducible. Please check the updated question for a link to a project which suffers from the issue. I created a new xamarin android project and installed the package into it, the exception does occur too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base is target to different version of android. For example: 60.1142.1 need MonoAndroid,Version=8.0. You could check this in each version's dependencies.
If you are using target api 25, you should use 42.1021.1