# IObserver is missing methods

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, observer-pattern

The `Observable` class already works, however I am still struggeling with the `IObserver`.

In the Xamarin documentation for the 'IObserver' it says, that I only have to implement the `Update()` method for the `interface IObserver`.

My problems:

1. when I add the `: IObserver` I get an error that I do not implement these two methods:

   ```
           public IntPtr Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

       public void Dispose()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   ```

   Why do I need these methods and what are they for? They are not mentioned in the Xamarin documentation.
2. When I add these methods, I get the follwing error message:
   error XA4212: Type `firstTry3.bluetoothConnectionActivity/deviceFoundObserver` implements `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject` but does not inherit `Java.Lang.Object` or `Java.Lang.Throwable`. This is not supported.
3. When I add `override` to the update method, the compiler says that there is no suitable method to override

Here is my code:

```
        public class deviceFoundObserver : IObserver
    {
        bluetoothConnectionActivity mActivity;

        public deviceFoundObserver(bluetoothConnectionActivity a)
        {
            mActivity = a;
        }

        //function is called from subject observable whenever a change happened
        public override void Update(Observable observable, Java.Lang.Object data)       //perhaps arguments like this: Observable observable, Object data
        {
            //there could be other messages as well, so first check wheather it is the right call from observer
            if ((string)data == deviceName)
            {
                mActivity.buttonStartEKG.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                Log.Info(constants.tag, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ": Observable called update function in Observer");
            }
        }
    }
```

I assume that I got something wrong in the way the Observer is used. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I need these methods and what are they for? They are not
>   mentioned in the Xamarin documentation.

Let's have a look at definition of `IObserver`:

```
namespace Java.Util
{
    public interface IObserver : IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        void Update(Observable o, Lang.Object arg);
    }
}
```

The two methods is not mentioned here, however we can find out that `IObserver` inherits from `IJavaObject` and `IDisposable`. Then go to the definition of `IJavaObject` and `IDisposable`:

```
namespace Android.Runtime
{
    public interface IJavaObject : IDisposable
    {
        IntPtr Handle { get; }
    }
}

namespace System
{
    public interface IDisposable
    {
        void Dispose();
    }
}
```

We can find the two methods here. **A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.** You should also implement the method defined in the `IJavaObject` and `IDisposable`.

> When I add these methods, I get the follwing error message: error
>   XA4212:.....

I did not get this error after add these methods. Try again and you can refer these similar questions:[error-xa4212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727884/build-xamarin-android-project-unsucessfully-error-xa4212), [implementing-java-interfaces](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72639/implementing-java-interfaces-without-inheriting-java-lang-object-should-fail-early).

> When I add override to the update method, the compiler says that there
>   is no suitable method to override

You **should not** add override to the update method. Just implement the method defined in the interface instead of override. You can have a look a [interface definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) here.